# Where can you actually use onclick in chrome.contextMenus.create?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my background script:

```
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "1",
        title: "abc",
        contexts: ['selection'],
        onclick: () => {}
    });
```

This causes an error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extensions using event pages or Service Workers cannot pass an onclick parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create. Instead, use the chrome.contextMenus.onClicked event.

Then, I tried to execute that code in a content script - I couldn't even create a context menu entry there, because that API seems to be unavailable from content scripts.

My question is then: where can I actually utilize the `onclick` callback?

Comment: Nowhere in MV3 because this parameter is only for a persistent background script.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it sepatatedly below (in the background script):
`chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(() => {})`
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/
Chrome extensions have many limitations.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing currently, however, I'd like to learn why the documented parameter (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#method-create) cannot be used.

Comment: It works with Manifest v2 but not with v3. So you can use it with Manifest v2.

Comment: I found this old [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=613563&q=chrome.contextMenus.create&can=1).
It'd seem that the onClick handler inside the create method is not allowed in case of a non-persistent background mv2 extension.
The API could be modified by removing the possibility of inserting this handler inside the creation.
If the Chromium team hasn't done this, it's for compatibility with those who use this technique with persistent background scripts (at least I think so).

Comment: @mnj
The reason is because with mv3 the event handlers have to be registered synchronously in the main thread, or rather, in the first event loop.

If you try to register an event handler in the SW inside a callback function or inside a .then().catch() it is likely that this handler will not be registered (and therefore will never respond to that particular event)